# Is there a probabilistic Turing machine whose halting probability is non-measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, computer-science, computability

I was wondering if there a [probabilistic turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_Turing_machine) whose halting probability is [non-measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set)? By that, I mean that the probability measure applied to the event "the machine halts" is undefined.

Comment: Incidentally, here's a super-nuke for this type of question: assuming large cardinals, in $L(\mathbb{R})$ every set is measurable and everything works nicely. Now how can a probabilistic Turing machine behave differently there? :P (More serious is the general motto, "Any computation theory is reasonably simple to define, and non-measurable sets are hard to define.")

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was about to say "have it look for a contradiction in L($\mathbb R$)", but then I realized it can't be inconsistent since its a model. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this can't happen (assuming we're fixing the input). The probability that a probabilistic Turing machine halts is given by the sum of the probabilities of each of the possible finite sequences of states which end in a halting configuration; there's no room for anything interesting to happen.

---

Incidentally, non-measurability really just applies to a given *space*, and there isn't one here explicitly. Of course we can shoehorn one in, viewing a probabilistic Turing machine as depending on an input *and* a point in an appropriate space representing the "sequence of events;" each reasonable such way, though, leads to the set of points yielding halting computations - after fixing the input, of course - being a low-complexity set (at worst, low-level Borel), well below the threshold for non-measurability.

For a controlled example, for any Turing machine $\Phi_e$ and any input $n$, the set of oracles $f\in 2^\omega$ for which $\Phi_e^f(n)$ halts is an **open** set since halting is ensured by some finite initial segment of $f$, and open sets are always measurable.=